# Android splash screen does not display image full screen

Tags: android

I have the code as below in my Android app.

My res/values/styles.xml:

```
   <style name="FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
   <item       name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
   </style>
```

res/drawable/background_splash.xml:

```
  <item

     android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

   <item>
      <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/image1"/>
   </item>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
      android:name=".SplashActivity"
      android:theme="@style/FullScreen">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

SplashActivity.java:

```
    public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,  MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
       }
    }
```

I have the image1 with appropriate resolution/size present in the res folder. But the splash screen does not display the image covering full screen but displays with reduced size only some part of the screen. Can you please advice what needs to be done. I went through some of the suggestions present on some sites but it did not help.

Comment: please post xml and make sure imageView property `ScrollType="fitXY"` ....

Comment: Share screen shot of your splash screen

Comment: How to I post an image to this comment box? sorry I am a newbie to stack overflow. appreciate your response.

Comment: edit your question to share your screenshot. and post your XML also...

Answer (score 24):

In your **res/drawable/background_splash.xml**, change **android:gravity**
you can use `fill`, in my case I used `top|fill_horizontal` for horizontal fill only, choose the combination you want.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:drawable="@color/White"/>

   <item>
       <bitmap
           android:gravity="top|fill_horizontal"
           android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jose exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: if resolution of image is less that screen then it does not work

Comment: Well, I didn't try it, but, I don't recommend to fill with smaller images

Comment: the hero we need, but not the one we deserve

Answer (score 1):

use parent of theme

parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Answer (score 1):

code for activity_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Code for Splash.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        },2000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
</LinearLayout
```

And use

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in your Activity code.

Comment: I tried the above solution but it still does fill the whole screen.

Comment: Does or does not?

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" or you can add this in your manifest under activity tag..

Comment: I am seeing below error when I tried adding above code in the Manifest under activity tag,    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ferainc.kudla/com.ferainc.kudla.SplashActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: Change the Java inheritance from ActionBarActivity to Activity. The reason you are having this problem is because the activity you are trying to apply the dialog theme to is extending ActionBarActivity.

Comment: I have updated to Activity as suggested and error is resolved but the original issue is still not resolved. The image does not fill the entire screen. `<activity
      android:name=".SplashActivity"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>`

Comment: use    android:background="@drawable/android" in your splash.xml. this might be the solution or i have commented the program below you can check this out.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your splash xml file has no padding of any sort. If any, delete.