# Java.Lang.RunTimeException Error When Attempting To Emulate App

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Building a splashscreen for Xamarin.Android project.  My error is the following:

```
com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp:drawable/splash_background_revised with resource ID #0x7f02012c ---> 
Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Drawable com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp:drawable/splash_background_revised with resource ID #0x7f02012c ---> 
Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_background_revised.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02012c ---> 
Android.Views.InflateException: Class not found RelativeLayout ---> 
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "RelativeLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
  at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "RelativeLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
  at at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
  at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:187)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:128)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1227)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1200)
  at at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:715)
  at at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
  at at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
  at at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2577)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2627)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2047)
  at at android.app.ActivityTransitionState.setEnterActivityOptions(ActivityTransitionState.java:158)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreateCommon(Activity.java:6674)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6681)
  at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at android.view.InflateException: Class not found RelativeLayout
  at at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:206)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:128)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1227)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1200)
  at at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:715)
  at at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
  at at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
  at at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2577)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2627)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2047)
  at at android.app.ActivityTransitionState.setEnterActivityOptions(ActivityTransitionState.java:158)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreateCommon(Activity.java:6674)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6681)
  at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
  at Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "RelativeLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
  at at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
  at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:187)
  at ... 24 more
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_background_revised.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02012c
  at at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:725)
  at at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
  at at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
  at at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2577)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2627)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2047)
  at at android.app.ActivityTransitionState.setEnterActivityOptions(ActivityTransitionState.java:158)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreateCommon(Activity.java:6674)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6681)
  at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
  at Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Class not found RelativeLayout
  at at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:206)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:128)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1227)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1200)
  at at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:715)
  at ... 20 more
  at Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "RelativeLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
  at at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
  at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:187)
  at ... 24 more
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp:drawable/splash_background_revised with resource ID #0x7f02012c
  at Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_background_revised.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02012c
  at at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:725)
  at at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
  at at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
  at at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2577)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2627)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2047)
  at at android.app.ActivityTransitionState.setEnterActivityOptions(ActivityTransitionState.java:158)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreateCommon(Activity.java:6674)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6681)
  at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
  at Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Class not found RelativeLayout
  at at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:206)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:128)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1227)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1200)
  at at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:715)
  at ... 20 more
  at Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "RelativeLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
  at at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
  at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:187)
  at ... 24 more
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp/md53db0ce6492013f19d1c303097dfcfb72.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp:drawable/splash_background_revised with resource ID #0x7f02012c
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
  at Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp:drawable/splash_background_revised with resource ID #0x7f02012c
  at Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_background_revised.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02012c
  at at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:725)
  at at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
  at at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
  at at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2577)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2627)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2047)
  at at android.app.ActivityTransitionState.setEnterActivityOptions(ActivityTransitionState.java:158)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreateCommon(Activity.java:6674)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6681)
  at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
  at Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Class not found RelativeLayout
  at at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:206)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:128)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1227)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1200)
  at at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:715)
  at ... 20 more
  at Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "RelativeLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.shaneckeney.spikeballsampleapp-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
  at at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
  at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:187)
  at ... 24 more
```

My XML code is as follows:

splash_background_revised.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/splashlogo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I change my XML code to use the following instead I can get around the error but I want to use ImageView for the container of the image that I am using so that I can scale it to fit better on the screen.

splash_background.xml

```
  <item>
    <color android:color="#FF000000"/>
  </item>
  <item>   
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splashlogo"
        android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

My styles.xml is listed below and I can simply change the android:windowBackground attribute to either splash_background.xml or splash_background_revised.xml with the first working and the second resulting in the Java.Lang.RunTimeException shown in the beginning.

```
<resources>

    <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
    <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background_revised</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

This is my first time using Xamarin and am building a sample mobile application for practice but cannot seem to find the answer anywhere on this.

Comment: try setting gravity="fill" or try out this thread
[Full Screen Splash Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164664/android-splash-screen-does-not-display-image-full-screen/39189040)

Comment: Did you try to delete the `bin` and `obj` folder in your project? Then re-build your project.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Clearing the bin and obj folders seemed to do the trick.  I now no longer get the exception error.  Thank you.

Comment: I am glad to hear that, I post his comment to the answer.  And please accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to delete the `bin` and `obj` folder in your project. Then re-build your project.This exeception will disappear.