# Hide Notch grey background when launching splash screen

Tags: react-native, layoutparams, android-layoutparams

**For react-native app on Android For the devices with Notch** -
I am able to use full screen mode on all screens except Splash screen by this code : This code basically uses full screen even behind the notch.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
           WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    layoutParams.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
    getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);

}
```

**I need to use full screen mode on Splash screen as well. It shows grey / default bg color as shown below.**

[image: t]

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42586696/11212074

Comment: When I use my drawer layout and then navigation layout in it
it shows brown area same as your in the notch. I am also using all your layout param commands after doing so many things, when I remove my drawer layout then my problem solved